# Get Event Log Message content in a Variable

Tags: powershell

I want to get the the first "WDS.Device.ID" (00-15-5D-8A-44-25) (without the [] brackets) into a variable.

I tried some RegEx things but without success as I lack the knowledge for it.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $result | fl


Message : A device query was successfully processed (status 0x0):

          Input:
          WDS.Request.Type='Deployment'
          WDS.Client.Property.Architecture.Process='X64'
          WDS.Client.Property.Architecture.Native='X64'
          WDS.Client.Property.Firmware.Type='BIOS'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Manufacturer='Microsoft Corporation'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Model='Virtual Machine'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Vendor='American Megatrends Inc.'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Version='090008 '
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.ChassisType='Desktop'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.UUID={CCD695BE-20AB-48CC-8F01-319B498F7A69}
          WDS.Client.Request.Version=1.0.0.0
          WDS.Client.Version=10.0.18362.1
          WDS.Client.Host.Version=10.0.18362.1
          WDS.Client.DDP.Default.Match=FALSE
          WDS.Device.ID=[00-15-5D-8A-44-25]
          WDS.Device.ID=[BE-95-D6-CC-AB-20-CC-48-8F-01-31-9B-49-8F-7A-69]


          Output:
          WDS.Client.Property.Architecture.Process='X64'
          WDS.Client.Property.Architecture.Native='X64'
          WDS.Client.Property.Firmware.Type='BIOS'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Manufacturer='Microsoft Corporation'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Model='Virtual Machine'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Vendor='American Megatrends Inc.'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.Version='090008 '
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.ChassisType='Desktop'
          WDS.Client.Property.SMBIOS.UUID={CCD695BE-20AB-48CC-8F01-319B498F7A69}
          WDS.Client.Request.Version=1.0.0.0
          WDS.Client.Version=10.0.18362.1
          WDS.Client.Host.Version=10.0.18362.1
          WDS.Client.DDP.Default.Match=FALSE
          WDS.Client.Request.ResendAuthenticated=TRUE
```

Comment: Try `$devideID = ([regex]'(?i)WDS\.Device\.ID=\[((?:[0-9a-f]{2}-){5}[0-9a-f]{2})\]').Match($message).Groups[1].Value`

Comment: It's nearly the exact solution! ;-) But before i must remote the first line of the event log message: "Message : A device query was successfully processed (status 0x0):"...how can i achieve that?

Comment: Why remove the first line? It won't affect the regex because that is only searching for the device ID

Comment: Thanks you're right! Tried again now it works :-)

Comment: Only i need to adapt the event message output a little bit before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.
If the message you show is inside a string variable (let's call it `$message`), then you can use regex to get the value for the `WDS.Device.ID` without the brackets like this:

```
$devideID = ([regex]'(?i)WDS\.Device\.ID=\[((?:[0-9a-f]{2}-){5}[0-9a-f]{2})\]').Match($message).Groups[1].Value
```

Result:

> 00-15-5D-8A-44-25

Regex details:

> ```
> WDS                Match the characters “WDS” literally
> \.                 Match the character “.” literally
> Device             Match the characters “Device” literally
> \.                 Match the character “.” literally
> ID=                Match the characters “ID=” literally
> \[                 Match the character “[” literally
> (                  Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    (?:             Match the regular expression below
>       [0-9a-f]     Match a single character present in the list below
>                    A character in the range between “0” and “9”
>                    A character in the range between “a” and “f”
>          {2}       Exactly 2 times
>       -            Match the character “-” literally
>    ){5}            Exactly 5 times
>    [0-9a-f]        Match a single character present in the list below
>                    A character in the range between “0” and “9”
>                    A character in the range between “a” and “f”
>       {2}          Exactly 2 times
> )                
> ]                  Match the character “]” literally
> ```

The `(?i)` in the regex makes it case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to go about it. this presumes the `$Result` variable holds one multiline string AND that the 1st `[` & the 1st `]` are "bracketing" your target data. [*grin*]

```
$Result.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0]
```

output = `00-15-5D-8A-44-25`